# Need to Populate a landing page with info from a DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am sending an email to subscribers with a coupon and the user info is in the email.  This part works fine.  I have set up a print coupon button which takes the subscriber to a landing page in Exact Target using "MicrositeUrl(XXXXXXX).  Then I have a snippet of JavaScript code to redirect to a print screen. Everything works except the subscriber info does not show on the coupon in the print screen.  How do I link my DE to pre-populate the landing page? I am a little new to the Ampscript code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As part of passing values from DE to your landing page. There is two ways of doing this.

1. Pass the necessary parameters in the [Microsite URL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/MicrositeURL.htm) within an email - when user clicks the link the values will be passed into the landing page and a [RequestParameter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/requestparameter.htm) can be used to grab the values.

Note: Any values from the sendable DE which you're using to send email can be passed on as a parameter to your landing page. Sample code.

```
%%=MicrositeURL(PageID, 'SubscriberKey', _subscriberkey, 'Email', emailaddr, 'Parameter1', 'DE_Field')=%%

%%[RequestParameter('your_parameters')]%%
```

2. You can also do a [Lookup](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/lookup/#Lookup) on the DE where the subscriber information is. The Lookup is set on the landing page which will do a RequestParameter call on **_subscriberkey** or **emailaddr**. Using these values the subscriber info can be pulled in from the DE.

> %%=Lookup("your_DE","column_to_return","column_to_identify","value_to_match")=%%

**Here is the specific solution to your question:**

**For Email:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <!--%%[ /* Set Up Android, Apple, Print URLs */ SET @promo_cd = '77WC1701' SET @PrintURL = MicrositeURL('xxxxxxx','first_name', first_name,'last_name',last_name,'vin',vin) ]%%-->
</head>

<body> <a href='%%=RedirectTo(@PrintURL)=%%'> <img src='image.mimet.mmsa.com/lib/fe6a15707664007e771c/m/5/…; style='display:inline-block;border:0;border:none;'></a> </body>

</html>
```

**For Landing Page**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <!--%%[

    SET @first_name = RequestParameter('first_name')
    SET @last_name = RequestParameter('last_name')
    SET @vin = RequestParameter('vin')

    ]%%-->
</head>

<body> 

<p>Here is the output:</p>
<p>%%=v(@first_name)=%%</p>
<p>%%=v(@last_name)=%%</p>
<p>%%=v(@vin)=%%</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Brad,  Here is my test email code.     <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>


<!--%%[
/* Set Up Android, Apple, Print URLs */

SET promo_cd = "77WC1701"
SET PrintURL = MicrositeURL('xxxxxxx',"first_name", first_name,"last_name",last_name,"vin",vin)


]%%-->

</head>

<body>
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(PrintURL)=%%">
       <img src="http://image.mimet.mmsa.com/lib/fe6a15707664007e771c/m/5/mitsuserviceprintbutton.jpg" style="display:inline-block;border:0;border:none;"></a>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Not sure I did this correctly.   so I want you to take a peek at it.  Like I mention this Ampscript thing is a new to me.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have updated the answer above. Please upvote and accept the answer if it helps.